# Canvas Text NullREference

Tags: c#, unity3d

Помогите не знаю в чём проблема выдаёт nullrefernce HPINFO.text = texthp;

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class HealthPercent : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image UIHP;
    public float HP = 1f;
    public GameObject ChildTransformH;
    public Text HPINFO;

    private void Update()
    {
        UIHP.fillAmount = HP;
        string hppercent = "%";
        int truehp = Mathf.RoundToInt(HP * 100);
        string texthp = truehp + hppercent;
        string deadhp = "0" + hppercent;
        if (HP > 0)
        {
            HPINFO.text = texthp;
        }
        else
        {
            HPINFO.text = deadhp;
            gameObject.transform.parent = null;
            gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("Dead", true);
        }

    }
    void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Dead") && (HP >= 0))
        {
            HP -= Time.deltaTime/10f; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: HPINFO не задан в инспекторе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HPINFO не определён

Надо либо задать его в инспекторе, либо сделать определение его в методе

```
void Awake() {
    text = gameObject.GetComponent<Text>(); // можно без "gameObject"
}
```

Comment: здравствуйте спасибо за ответ, не много не понимаю. если можно поподробнее. спасибо!

Comment: @Azazel что именно не понимаете?

Comment: проблема в том что скрипт висит на игроке, а не на тексте поэтому так не получается.

Comment: @Azazel а текст в игроке или где-то ещё?  Если в одном из объектов игрока, то [https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2019.4/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentInChildren.html](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2019.4/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentInChildren.html)   ....... так или иначе 1-ый способ задания через инспектор всё ещё доступен